# Adjust Width % of Wordpress Widget

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, width

my website sidebar widgets look fine when I view www.aryaziai.com from my desktop. However, The ONLY issue I have is that when I view my mobile version of my site, the "featured video" sidebar sticks out of the frame and overlaps a bit with the black background.

At the end of the day I don't want to manually change the width/height of the youtube video, I just want the width of the "featured video" widget to automatically resize to the size of widget title (the blue block thing).. Its interesting because the size of the youtube video is the same as the widget title when viewing on a desktop, but the widget title remains at a perfect size in the mobile..

Any 100% width codes out there that can fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're having a problem getting your YouTube video to adjust to the screen width even if the `div` you're wrapping it in is correctly resized.  If so, please read [Chris Coyier's article on resizing YouTube videos](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/).

You can do all of this in jQuery (if you're using it), here's Chris' code:

```
$(function() {

    // Find all YouTube videos
    var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

        // The element that is fluid width
        $fluidEl = $("body");

    // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
    $allVideos.each(function() {

        $(this)
            .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

            // and remove the hard coded width/height
            .removeAttr('height')
            .removeAttr('width');

    });

    // When the window is resized
    // (You'll probably want to debounce this)
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

        // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
        $allVideos.each(function() {

            var $el = $(this);
            $el
                .width(newWidth)
                .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

        });

    // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
    }).resize();

});
```

Comment: Less emphases on the youtube part, and more on the widget % css stuff

Comment: Pardon?  I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I want a code that will set the max width of widget content to the width of the sidebar widget title. Thanks for the code but the youtube comment I made was just an example of things that overlap in the mobile overview

Comment: Then what I would do is set a width to your parent container and then give it a padding.